# Show value for custom type in object inspector

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

While you are debugging in QtCreator, the object inspector shows a column named **Value**. For native types it shows their value, but *QString* is not a native value and its value is shown too.

[image: Object inspector in Qt Creator]

In this picture, *foo_object* is a custom type and I want to show its description. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't think so. `QString` is not a primitive type, but it stores plain old chars, which is something that can be displayed by the object inspector.

Comment: Most IDE's allow you to specify which member variable contains the primary data to display in object inspector like lists. This is usually done through some configuration file in your home directory or the directory where the IDE is installed (or one of it's sub-directories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a custom complex type to show up properly in Qt Creator's object inspector you should either use an existing or write your own [debugging helper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debugging-helpers.html).

They basically allows you to define how your data should be interpreted.

Comment: That's exactly I was looking for, thank you! In addition to oficial Qt link that you provide to me, I found [this one](http://plohrmann.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/writing-debug-visualizers-for-gdb.html) that I think it is more clear.